# pass PHP variable value into SQL IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this sql query.

```
  select something from sometable WHERE `word` IN ('stand','on','in') GROUP BY (`p_id`)  LIMIT 1000
```

And I have a php variable ($words) which holds a sentence. How to pass that variable value into this IN clause?

ex: $words = "stand on in this here";

Comment: Not the exact duplicate of that question. Because in my case I have a large sentence to put into IN clause.

Comment: Step 1 - replace all the spaces with commas.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = explode(" ", $words); // GEt each word in array
$in_stmt = "'".implode("','", $array)."'"; // create a string like 'stand','on','in'
```

**BETTER**:

```
$in_stmt = "'".str_replace(" ", "','", $words)."'";
```

MySQL Statement:

```
$stmt = "select something from sometable WHERE `word` IN (".$in_stmt.") GROUP BY (`p_id`)  LIMIT 1000"
```

Comment: Welcome. Check my updated post. That is more efficient.

Comment: By the way in my $words variable contains apostrophes and commas some times. Then the query will be injected. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: before string replace you can use `mysql_real_escape_string` or `mysqli_real_escape_string` refer docs for more details. http://in2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php and http://in2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: But I'm using cakephp. In cake php I cannot use real_escape_string function. What can I do?

Comment: I am not familiar with cakephp. If I am not wrong cakephp is just a framework. It should allow php mysql functions. And you can also check `addslashes` and `strpslashes`. But I am not sure if it will work for you.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for helping me. I'll try those functions.